# Detecting row changes without a LastModified stamp?

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table which doesn't have any last modified dates on it. I then take a copy of this table and move it to a BI environment for reporting purposes - this is currently a truncate and load process.

What I would like to do is each time the process runs, to only bring over the rows that are either new or have changed since the last load - is there any other way of doing this without using EXCEPT? (As the table is really large in size and I want the process to run as quick as possible)

So for any new rows we would insert these, for any modified ones we would update them.

I would use a MERGE statement however I am just struggling to find a way to identify the last modified rows without a timestamp.

Comment: If *you* don't know how to tell if a row has been amended in *your* environment, how would we know? If you don't have a column that denotes something has changed (like a `rowversion` column or a datetime with the "last updated" time) then you're going to need to check every column, or use an `EXCEPT`; which is very likely going to be slow with large sets of data.

Comment: You should consider creating a trigger and copy/update the inserted/updated row as soon as it is done in the source table.